# SQL Server - Counting number of times an attribute in a dataset changes (non-concurrently)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, gaps-and-islands

I have a query that returns either a 1 or 0 based on whether or not an event occurred on a given date. This is ordered by date. Basically, a simple result set is:

```
Date         |  Type
---------------------
2010-09-27      1
2010-10-11      1
2010-11-29      0
2010-12-06      0
2010-12-13      1
2010-12-15      0
2010-12-17      0
2011-01-03      1
2011-01-04      0
```

What I would now like to be able to do is to count the number of separate, non-concurrent instances of '0's there are - i.e. count how many different groups of 0s appear.

In the above instance, the answer should be 3 (1 group of 2, then another group of 2, then finally 1 to end with).

Hopefully, the above example illustrates what I am trying to get at. I have been searching for a while, but am finding it difficult to succinctly describe what I am looking for, and hence haven't found anything of relevance.

Thanks in advance,

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variant of the "islands" problem. My first answer uses Itzik Ben Gan's double `row_number` trick to identify contiguous groups of data efficiently. The combination of `Type,Grp` identifies each individual island in the data.

[You can read more about the different approaches to tackling this problem here.](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf)

```
;WITH T AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date) -
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Date)  AS Grp
    FROM    YourTable
)
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT Grp)
FROM    T
WHERE Type=0
```

My second answer requires a single pass through the data. It is not guaranteed to work but is on the same principle as a technique that many people successfully use to concatenate strings without problems.

```
DECLARE @Count int = 0

SELECT @Count = CASE WHEN Type = 0 AND @Count <=0 THEN -@Count+1 
                     WHEN Type = 1 AND @Count > 0 THEN - @Count
                     ELSE @Count END

FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Date

SELECT ABS(@Count)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could give each row a number in a CTE.  Then you can join the table on itself to find the previous row.  Knowing the previous row, you can sum the number of times the previous row is 1 and the current row is 0.  For example:

```
; with NumberedRows as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by date) as rn
        ,       type
        from    YourTable
        )
select  sum(case when cur.type = 0 and IsNull(prev.type,1) = 1 then 1 end)
from    NumberedRows cur
left join    
        NumberedRows prev
on      cur.rn = prev.rn + 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a left join (since you're already using IsNull because you've recognised that the first row might be 0)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I was thinking about something along the lines of this, but felt like it might be bending the relational model a little too much - it felt a little procedural. Is this just the route I'm going to have to go down?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example, using Sql Server 2005+

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Date DATETIME,
        Type INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2010-09-27',1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2010-10-11',1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2010-11-29',0
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2010-12-06',0
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2010-12-13',1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2010-12-15',0
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2010-12-17',0
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2011-01-03',1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2011-01-04',0

;WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date) ROWID
    FROM    @Table
)
SELECT  v.*
FROM    Vals v LEFT JOIN
        Vals vNext ON   v.ROWID + 1 = vNext.ROWID
WHERE   v.Type = 0
AND     (vNext.Type = 1 OR vNext.Type IS NULL)
```

Comment: +1, only it should be `SELECT COUNT...`, right? For that's what the OP is after.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to show the detail of what teh query got to.